# PHP JSON Highcharts load database result

Tags: php, jquery, database, json, highcharts

I'm stuck!

I need to create highchart with json result. I found some sources here but can't put this to work.

The closest I can get was doing this:

**Chart options:**

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'tudo',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
        rightMargin: 80
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Weekdays'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: somewhere in a calendar'
    },

     xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
    }
    },

    yAxis: [
        {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
             }
        },
        {
            linkedTo: 0,
            opposite: true
        }
    ],

    series: []
};
```

**ajax call:**

```
$.getJSON('ajax/calc.ajax.php', function(data) {

        var series = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

            series.name = key;
            series.data = value;

            options.series.push(name);
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

highchart loads ok, and fills the series with `Series 1, Series 2 ....`

but no graphic is made, he keeps blank. ( something like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPAUx/1789/)).

wanna know if I'm missing something or everything.

Thanks

**update: i change the sql, now i'm working with 2 fields, and with this, the grafic work perfect, now i just want to know if doing like this its ok.**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

        while(!$res->EOF){

            //$json = array("group" => "Web", "action" => "list");
            $json[$res->fields["DESMAR"]] = array(intval($res->fields["QTD"]));
            //$json["users"] = array(array("name" => "JulioGreff", "status" => "online"));
            $res->MoveNext();
        }

        echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: What does the returned `data` look like in your ajax call?

Comment: dont know if is this what u want, but returns [object Object]

Comment: json by firebug = {"nome":"TRANSFORMADOR 250VA 0-230-380V \/ 0,24V-0-48V","modelo":"TRANSFORMADOR","marca":"SEIT","valor":"318.87|542.08","qtdade":"0"}

Comment: edit some values: `{"nome":"TRANSFORMADOR 250VA 0-230-380V \/ 0,24V-0-48V","valor":"318.87|542.08","qtdade":"0"}` , this is the correct return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **ajax call** -

```
$.getJSON('ajax/calc.ajax.php', function(data) {
    var series = []; // <---------------------- must be object not array
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        series.name = key;
        series.data = value;
        options.series.push(name); // <-------- it should be series not name
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

So, it would be as follows -

```
$.getJSON('ajax/calc.ajax.php', function(data) {        
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var series = {}; // <-------------------- moved and changed to object
        series.name = key;
        series.data = value;
        options.series.push(series); // <-------- pushing series object
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

Also, considering the JSON you are receiving -

> {"nome":"TRANSFORMADOR 250VA 0-230-380V / 0,24V-0-48V","modelo":"TRANSFORMADOR","marca":"SEIT","valor":"318.87|542.08","qtdade":"0"??}

what you are doing in the `$.each` -

```
series.data = value;
```

does not make sense.

**series.data** is an array. So, it could look like **either** as follows -

```
[y1, y2, y3, ....] // array of numbers (which are y values)
```

**or** as follows -

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ....] // array of arrays of pair of numbers (x and y values)
```

**or** as follows -

```
// array of objects which can have x and y values as properties
[{                       
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

So, make sure that your PHP code produces a JSON that matches an array of one of the above, then `series.data = value` inside your `$.each` will work.

**Update:**
Sorry, I do Java and have never done PHP so can't help you much with PHP. But, can you try with the following as your PHP, just to see if the chart shows up?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$return_data = array(
    array(array(10, 20), array(20, 30), array(56, 30), array(50, 20)),
    array(array(10, 0), array(20, 10), array(56, 100), array(50, 40))
);
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

**Update:** To render pie while keeping the same PHP.

```
$.getJSON('ajax/calc.ajax.php', function(data) {        
    var series = { // <-------------------- create just one series object
        type: 'pie',
        data: [] //data array for new series
    }; 
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        series.data.push([key, value[0]]);            
    });
    options.series.push(series); // <-------- pushing series object
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

This should draw pie chart.

Comment: just a note, i dont know if php side its right to, will modify the question ( php part )  to show only the necessary.

Comment: can u show me a example in php how to do it ? series are working.

Comment: i'm trying something here, and i change the php to this, and the yAxis appears, but i did not understand the process: `$return_data = array('valor' => '15');`

Comment: yes, meanwhile i did something here, and work, will update the main question , take a look and tell me if its good or not! :) - edit: check the update

Comment: @ric_bfa: Can you show the final json produced by your new PHP?

Comment: firebug:  `{"series1":[10809],"series2":[4017],"series3":[2695],"series4":[1896],"series5":[52],"series6":[45]}`

Comment: funny is only bar and column work , i have to change the array to make a `pie` or any other else work.

Comment: @ric_bfa: Are you really trying to plot that many series, all with just one point?

Comment: @ric_bfa: According to your JS code inside `$.each`, if you take this `"series1":[10809]` as an example, __series1__ will end up as __key__ and __[10809]__ will end up as __value__, and you assign __key__ as name of your new series and __value__ as data of the new series. And the fact is __[10809]__ contains only one number. So, that's a new series with one point. And the same will happen for all the pairs in in your json.

Comment: yes, the `while` are doing this , the result work perfect, each series have your individual value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4389/discussion-between-ric-bfa-and-bhesh-gurung)

Comment: check this question @Bhesh Gurung, see if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826447/each-only-shows-one-series-highcharts

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem lies in your PHP code. Highcharts expects a series to follow [a particular format](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series). In your case, things work out (partly) because `name` is one of the field it is looking for. The data, however, needs to be in one of three formats:

- An array of y values (e.g. `[0, 1, 2]`)
- An array of arrays (x, y values; e.g. `[[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]]`)
- An array of objects meeting using [point properties](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point)

You would want the last format, I think. For example:

```
var series = [];
series.name = "series1";
series.data = {y: 10}; //very minimalistic example of the object format
options.series.push(name);
```

To get your code to work, you might need to change the inside of your `$.each` function to something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    series.name = key;

    series.data = {
        y: value.property_you_are_interested_in
    };

    options.series.push(name);
});
```

...of course, if you wanted to use one of the other forms, it would be pretty easy as well:

```
//First form (array of y values)
var series = {};
series.data = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    series.name = key;
    series.data.push(value.property_you_are_interested_in);
});
options.series.push(series);

//Second form (array of x, y values)
var series = {};
series.data = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    series.name = key;
    series.data.push([value.X_property_you_are_interested_in, value.Y_property_you_are_interested_in]);
});
options.series.push(series);
```

Comment: note: i'm showing only one db result, but the correct is return more then one line