# $.each only shows one series highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Focusing in this question: [php-json-highcharts-load-database-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810098/php-json-highcharts-load-database-result)

The answer was to do the follow `each`:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/calc.ajax.php', function(data) {        
    var series = { // <-------------------- create just one series object
        type: 'pie',
        data: [] //data array for new series
    }; 
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        series.data.push([key, value[0]]);
    });
    options.series.push(series); // <-------- pushing series object
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
});
```

This works using pie charts, and if I change to another type (`line` for example), the same `$.each` will do the work except showing more then one series. I've already tryied putting the series inside the each, but without success.

How can I make this work? In the highchart docs, if the series came with  `name` , the name will appear as series. like this:

```
    {
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Apple' // showing only once
        data: []
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because pie and line chart have different format of series.data.
Example of series.data for pie chart:

```
     series: [{
     type: 'pie',
     name: 'Browser share',
     data: [
        ['Firefox',   45.0],
        ['IE',       26.8],
        {
           name: 'Chrome',    
           y: 12.8,
           sliced: true,
           selected: true
        },
        ['Safari',    8.5],
        ['Opera',     6.2],
        ['Others',   0.7]
     ]
  }]
```

Example of series.data for line chart:

```
     series: [{
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
     }, {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
     }, {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
     }, {
         name: 'London',
         data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
     }]
```